# how to replace ping Id with Azure?

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory, ping

I am working on maven project and using ping federation user  authentication but nw want to change it to azure .Any idea how to change ping to azure?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: My question is basically how to use azure authentication in spring project?